# Gradle dependency vs. java import statement in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I'm trying to pull together an Android project, it includes several library packages, and a demo app that utilize the libraries.

I'm using Android Studio and Gradle. (I used to work with Eclipse, without gradle.)

So here in Android Studio, I have a project including several packages(or modules? what's the difference in concept?)

I have a core library project. And another library, say Flavor, that utilizes core.

In the Flavor module,

In `build.gradle` file, I have

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile project(':**core-project**')
    ....
}
```

I understand it as that Gradle add the core project build path to my Flavor project. (Same way that you can do it manually in Eclipse. See picture)
[image]

In java file,

```
import org.project.**core**; //this shows Unused

public MyFlavorClass extends CoreClass {
   ...
}
```

I deleted the import statement and it seems fine. 
So why the import statement is not needed here?

Comment: Please share the package names of MyFlavorClass and CoreClass.

Comment: If `MyFlavorClass` is in the same package name where your imports are, the import won't be needed since they belong to the same package (independently of were that package was created) and are naturally visible. That's just java and nothing to do with gradle.